# Possible Virus?

Tags: google-play-store, battery, samsung-galaxy-s-5, malware

[image]

This message keeps appearing on my phone. There are misspelled words, and my coworker who has the same phone has never had this issue.

Comment: It seems like spam rather than a virus, although the app it's trying to get you to install might do more nefarious things.  Have to tried to install an antivirus app / spamkiller /etc.?

Answer (score 0):

It is not any virus . Its simply ad. Check which app you installed recently, it might be a third party app. Just ignore that message it doesn't harm your phone.

Comment: `Just ignore that message it doesn't harm your phone.` -- That might be true, but how are you so certain? Security advices doesn't really work on opinions or extremely personal experiences! How about a source or something to corroborate your claim. *Matthew Read* mentioned something good in comment under the question.